# How can I make my RecyclerView behind a FloatingActionsMenu fully scrollable?

Tags: android, xml, scroll, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I have written this app that shows Bus routes at my university. The App itself is working fine but there is a problem with the Layout:
Not all of my RecyclerView is scrollable, as you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSl8F.jpg) picture.
The green square is scrollable, but the red one does not scroll, even if the FloatingActionsMenu is no expanded.

The FloatingActionsMenu is made with [this](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) library.

The XML-Code for the RecyclerView and the FloatingActionsMenu is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/aachen_background">

....

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/multi_cards"
        android:layout_below="@id/maincard" />


       <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
           android:id="@+id/action_button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:clickable="true"
           fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/fab_color"
           app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/fab_color"
           fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/black_semi_transparent"
           fab:fab_addButtonSize="normal"
           fab:fab_labelsPosition="left"
           fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
           app:fab_addButtonStrokeVisible="false"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/maincard">
           <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
               android:id="@+id/find_activity"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_title="@string/find_activity"
               fab:fab_icon="@mipmap/find_activity"
               fab:fab_size="mini" />

           <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

               android:id="@+id/appointment_finder"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_title="@string/appointment_finder"
               fab:fab_icon="@mipmap/appointment_finder"
               fab:fab_size="mini"/>

           <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

               android:id="@+id/new_ralph"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_title="@string/new_ralph"
               fab:fab_icon="@mipmap/new_ralph"
               fab:fab_size="mini"/>




       </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have already tried:

- setting the android:visibility attribute to GONE or VISIBLE base on the isExpanded()-State of the FloatingActionsMenu
- setting android:duplicateParentState="true"

The Full XML-Code of this Screen is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/aachen_background">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/maincard"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/maincard_corner_radius">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">
            <!-- Left Part: Time and beneath Calendar RalphEvent -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="174dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/maincard_get_up_time"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textSize="60sp"
                    android:text="@string/maincard_get_up_time"
                    android:textColor="@color/maincard_text_color"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/maincard_event_start"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="@string/maincard_event_start"
                    android:textColor="@color/maincard_text_color"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/maincard_event_title"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:text="@string/maincard_event_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/maincard_text_color"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/maincard_event_location"
                    android:text="@string/maincard_event_location"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/maincard_text_color"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Right Part: Weather and Transportation Info -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:gravity="right">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/weather_icon"
                        android:id="@+id/maincard_weather_icon"
                        android:src="@drawable/weather_icon_rain" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/maincard_weather"
                        android:text="@string/maincard_weather"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/maincard_secondary_color" />


                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/bus_icon"
                        android:id="@+id/maincard_transport_icon"
                        android:src="@drawable/transport_icon_bus" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/maincard_departure_time"
                        android:text="@string/maincard_departure_time"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/maincard_secondary_color" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/multi_cards"
        android:layout_below="@id/maincard" />


       <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
           android:id="@+id/action_button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:clickable="true"
           fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/fab_color"
           app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/fab_color"
           fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/black_semi_transparent"
           fab:fab_addButtonSize="normal"
           fab:fab_labelsPosition="left"
           fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
           app:fab_addButtonStrokeVisible="false"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:layout_below="@+id/maincard">
           <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
               android:id="@+id/find_activity"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_title="@string/find_activity"
               fab:fab_icon="@mipmap/find_activity"
               fab:fab_size="mini" />

           <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

               android:id="@+id/appointment_finder"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_title="@string/appointment_finder"
               fab:fab_icon="@mipmap/appointment_finder"
               fab:fab_size="mini"/>

           <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

               android:id="@+id/new_ralph"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/fab_color"
               fab:fab_title="@string/new_ralph"
               fab:fab_icon="@mipmap/new_ralph"
               fab:fab_size="mini"/>




       </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</RelativeLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about removing this line from your FloatingActionsMenu?:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set main layout as frame.
Try this:

```
<FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout>

        <CardView />

        <RecyclerView />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FloatingActionsMenu />

</FrameLayout>
```